# Galois covering of Projective line over rational numbers. cyclic groups, inverse galois problem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, galois-theory

I was reading from the book Topics in Galois Theory by J. P. Serre ,

I was trying to understand, How given a group $G$, we can construct covering of $P^{1}$ such that the Galois group associated to covering is $G$.

First I started with complex numbers, 
over complex numbers we can take the map $P^{1}\longrightarrow P^{1}$ defied by $z$ going to $z^{n}$,

But what about over rational numbers, I have looked whole book, but it was not able to find any result related to cyclic covering of projective line over rationals.

Comment: You already posted a question almost exactly like this before, I posted a question to you in the comments, and you never responded. There are no Galois coverings of $\mathbb{P}^1$ that are non-trivial over $\mathbb{C}$. You wrote down a cover ramified at $\infty$ and $0$. Over $\mathbb{Q}$ there are Galois coverings of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ but they are all of the form $\mathbb{P}^1_L\to\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ for $L$ some number field--they're Galois group is $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$. Thus, really, you're trying to solve the inverse Galois problem.

Comment: If you only care about *ramified* coverings, then *every* finite group occurs as the Galois group of a ramified covering of the projective line. Is that what you're interested in?

Comment: Yes, you are right . Any reference. ?

Comment: @AlexYoucis  Given a cyclic group (finite ) , Can we construct a branched cover of $P^{1}$ over rational number, such that the Galois group is cyclic. If you know any reference for this kindly mention it.

Comment: @AlexYoucis You mentioned a result in your comment," all Galois covering of $P^{1}$ over rational has the form .... .  " . From where I can read  about this result.

Comment: The fact about ramified coverings, say over $\mathbb{C}$ (which one can then easily deduce the result over $\mathbb{Q}$), comes from the fact that $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1-S)$ (where $S$ is some finite set of points) is free on $\#(S)-1$ generators. Thus, given any group $G$ which is generated by $n-1$ things it's clear you can create a branched cover of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ (branched at this $S$) with Galois group that group. The result about coverings of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ (ACTUAL coverings, not branched coverings) comes from the well-known exact sequence

Comment: $1\to \pi_1(X_{\overline{k}})\to \pi_1(X)\to G_k\to 1$ combined with the fact that $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}})=0$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I did not understand your last comment, Can you put it as an answer, I will happily accept it as an answer. can you please elaborate. It will be  helpful if you can give details also